# How to add an image in Report Viewer with SQL

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB.Net 2013 with SQL Server

What is the problem with my code? Is there something missing?

When I try to select the location, it show me in the Form the name, location  and the image.
Everything looks good, the only problem is that the image in report viewer doesn't change.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Table_locationBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Table_locationBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.Table_locationBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.KankonDataSet)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'KankonDataSet.Table_location' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Table_locationTableAdapter.Fill(Me.KankonDataSet.Table_location)

        If NamelocationComboBox.Text = Nothing Then
            NamelocationComboBox.Text = "No thing"
        End If

        If IdlocationTextBox.Text = Nothing Then
            IdlocationTextBox.Text = "No thing"
        End If

        Dim Param1 As New ReportParameter("ReportParameterlocation", NamelocationComboBox.Text)
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(Param1)
        Dim Param2 As New ReportParameter("ReportParameterwhere", IdlocationTextBox.Text)
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(Param2)

        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReportViewer1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ReportViewer1.Load
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    End Sub

    Private Sub NamelocationComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NamelocationComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim Param1 As New ReportParameter("ReportParameterlocation", NamelocationComboBox.Text)
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(Param1)
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    End Sub

    Private Sub IdlocationTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles IdlocationTextBox.TextChanged
        Dim Param2 As New ReportParameter("ReportParameterwhere", IdlocationTextBox.Text)
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(Param2)
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Image in Attachments!

[image]

[image]

Comment: anyone would like help me please!

Comment: Please am looking for help.